Efficient Method to Calculate the Determinant

Given a matrix, the task is to find its eigenvectors.
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
190 & 156 & -104 & -16 \\
-182 & -148 & 104 & 16 \\
115.5 & 99 & -58 & -15 \\ 
-115.5 & -99 & 66 & 23 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I applied $det(A-\lambda I)$, then added the first and second rows, as well as the third and fourth, aiming to obtain a block matrix. This resulted in a determinant
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
8-\lambda & 8-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
-182 & -148-\lambda & 104 & 16 \\
115.5 & 99 & -58-\lambda & -15 \\ 
0 & 0 & 8-\lambda & 8-\lambda \end{vmatrix}
$$
Then, I got stuck. Is there an efficient method to compute the characteristic equation for this matrix?

I would probably develop this by the first or last row.

You must now do $C_2:=C_2-C_1$ and $C_3:=C_3-C_4$, then the problem is reduced to a $2\times 2$ one.

Indeed, following ancient mathematician's hint and developing
by the rows with the most amount of zeroes:

\begin{align}\det\begin{pmatrix}8-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\-182 & 34-\lambda & 88 & 16 \\115.5 & -16.5 & -43-\lambda & -15 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 8-\lambda \end{pmatrix}=(8-\lambda)^2\det\pmatrix{34-\lambda&88\\-16.5&-43-\lambda}\end{align}

yields
\begin{align}
&(8-\lambda)^2(\lambda^2+9\lambda-10)=\lambda^4-7\lambda^3-90\lambda^2+736\lambda-640\,.
\end{align}
